# Nested Navigation Controllers and TabBar Controllers

Tags: swift, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have my Storyboard like this:

```
TabBarViewController
|-NavigationViewController
  |-TableViewController
```

This helps me have a navigation bar AND tab bar at the same time in TableViewController.

Now I am trying to add a SecondViewController to show details of the item chosen in the table. So I did this:

```
TabBarViewController
|-NavigationViewController
  |-TableViewController
    |-SecondViewController
```

But SecondViewController does not show the navigation bar. So I tried this:

```
TabBarViewController
|-NavigationViewController
  |-TableViewController
    |-NavigationViewController
      |-SecondViewController
```

But still no navigation bar in SecondViewContrller.
What am I missing?

Comment: You only need one NavigationViewController. Are you using segues? If so, is there a segue connecting TableViewController to SecondTableViewController?

Comment: Yes, I have a "Show" segue from `TableViewController` to `SecondViewController`when I do not use the second navigation controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure why you need the nested Navigation Controllers like this?

See below for a Storyboard-only solution that I think is what you want, or you can create a custom delegate to handle the view stack and navigation tree.

I'm assuming here that your 'SecondViewController' is a detail view of sorts? So, something like:

```
TabBarViewController
|-NavigationViewController
  |-TableViewController (NavigationViewControllerDelegate)
    |-DetailViewController (SecondViewController)
```

Here is the Storyboard solution (no code):

1. Add a `NavigationController` to the Storyboard
2. Embed it in a tab bar controller (from menu)
3. Add a `TableViewController` to the Storyabord
4. Add a button to a cell in the tableview
5. Add a standard `ViewController` to the Storyboard
6. Connect the tableview cell's button to the new view controller
7. Add another standard `ViewController` to the Storyboard and give it a tab bar item
8. Link the tab bar controller to this view controller

[image]

You then end up with something like this:

[image]

Comment: You are right. It does work. Turned out I do have a `navigationbar` on `SecondViewController`, but its background and back arrow color are all white so it is invisible. I changed the background color of view in SecondViewController and I am good now!